# Using injected web3.js in Vuex as a plugin

Tags: web3js

I would like to use web3 inside the store as a Vuex plugin, so I can call `this.web3` inside actions and mutations without having to pass the web3 instance from my components to the store. But since the store is compiled before web3 is injected, I'm wondering if it's even possible to write a plugin which could work like this.

I'm using Nuxt.js, by the way. So maybe there's something within Nuxt that would make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using web3 as part of the vue instance (ie `this.web3 = window.web3` caused errors). Instead I ended up moving all of my contract logic into a separate js file and including it in my store then accessing it as a getter. You can check out the method i used for the external js [here](https://github.com/okwme/clovers-dapp/blob/master/app/src/assets/clovers.js) and the vuex store [here](https://github.com/okwme/clovers-dapp/blob/master/app/src/store/index.js). maybe that implementation works for you.

otherwise there is a `vue-cli` repo for using truffle that integrates web3 inside of vuex [here](https://github.com/wilfreddenton/vue-truffle-webpack)